# 2 older IIS 7 Servers moving to 1 new IIS 10 Server. Got 1 working, how do I get the second one in?

Tags: iis, webserver

I've got 2 IIS 7 servers, each has a couple of apps/sites under the "Default Website" directory. I used MSDeploy to package and deploy one of them, and fixed some assembly and pointer issues to get the sites up and running. Then I used MSDeploy to package and deploy the second server, and it totally overwrote the "Default Website" wasting about an entire days work. How can I get the other apps/sites that are under Default Website "merged" into the new Default Website without overwriting what's already there. Thoughts?

Comment: Is your issue solved? If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue. If your issue still exists then try to refer the solution given by the community members. If then also you have any further questions then let us know about it. We will try to provide further suggestions to solve the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default behavior if you import configuration it will override the editing one. to avoid this behavior you have to try a workaround for this. use iis web deploy command line to export and import the site and application pool:

To Export all your website:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /config /xml > c:\sites.xml
```

This will export all the websites on your webserver, therefore you need to edit the sites.xml and remove the websites that you do not need to import for example:

Default Website
And all other websites that already exist on the second webserver. or you could rename it and then import it.

To Import the website:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add site /in < c:\sites.xml
```

To Export the Application Pools on IIS :

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool /config /xml > c:\apppools.xml
```

To import the Application Pools:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < c:\apppools.xml
```

It’s also possible to export a single website or application pool all you need to do is add the name of the Application Pool or Website to the command line:

To export/import a single application pool:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list apppool “MyAppPool” /config /xml > c:\myapppool.xml
```

Import:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add apppool /in < c:\myapppool.xml
```

To export/import a single website:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site “MyWebsite” /config /xml > c:\mywebsite.xml
```

Import:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd add site /in < c:\mywebsite.xml
```